# <CLOSED> MySQL Errcode 28 - No space left on device

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie to MySQL.
I have a free MySQL database from freesqldatabase.com. I have one table that's working fine. However, when I try to create a new table, I get presented with "Error writing file '/tmp/' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)" (where  is the name of the table).

freesqldatabase.com says that I have used 99.6% of my allocated 5.0MB, however my existing table only takes up 0.02MB. Why is this so? Is this the reason why I cannot create another table? How do I solve this problem?

I have seen some solutions saying to execute `du -sh /var/log/mysql.log`. But what is this? Where do I execute this? I am really confused...

I'm a 15 year-old hobbyist programmer and I just started learning SQL last week. I know nothing about Linux though :(
I really appreciate any help that I can get :)

Edit: I have $0 budget for now so my only options for SQL databases are free ones like freesqldatabase.com

Edit: SOLVED with assistance from the database provider.

Comment: MYSQL is not the only free RDBMS out there.

Comment: hi why you not take MySQL from official site : https://www.mysql.com/

Comment: (du mean disk usage) related to this blog : https://webdevetc.com/blog/linux-command-cheatsheet-disk-usage-and-filesize-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the log space issues unless this is on a freesqldatabase site or specifically references this.

5M is really tiny to play with. I'd assume freesqldatabase's calculation is a small amount in error.

To continue your SQL learning I'd install MySQL onto your local operating system and there are windows and osx installs.

Alternately low cost hosting companies can provide a VM for a low amount enough to learn.

Comment: I cant do anything with my database because of the log space issues; I can't ignore them. And I have no budget so I can only use free MySQL/SQL options :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on a Linux server, there was a file named **log_general.log** under **/var/lib/mysql** which occupied a large space. So deleting it and restarting MySQL worked for me.